# Create DraggableScrollableSheet with hole at top midle

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

I need something like this but I have 0 idea how realize that.
[image with what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FwXY.png)

I'm trying to achieve a specific UI effect in my Flutter application where I need to create a container with a hole in the top middle. I want to display an image within this container while having a transparent hole at the specified position.

I've looked into methods like ClipPath and ClipRect, but I'm having trouble achieving the desired effect. I want the hole to be responsive and adaptable to different screen sizes.

I would appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to implement this in Flutter. Thank you in advance for your help!